# @Transactional(readOnly = true) for JTA transactions

Tags: spring, jta, spring-transactions, bitronix

If we set a method with **@Transactional(readOnly = true)** over a **JTA** transaction will it optimize the transaction for Hibernate or simply ignore the attribute?

I am using **Spring Boot** and **Bitronix** and many times my transactions are getting timeout. Is it still a good practice to apply or should only set transaction for write/update operations?

Comment: `readOnly` is just a hint. If you have timeouts, that's not going to help I am afraid.

Comment: Ok, I agree about the timeout. But in relation of JTA, do you know if read-only works with @Transactional?

Comment: JTA is just a coordinator between several transactional resources. If you have two databases using hibernate, we're just going to propagate the flag as does `JpaTransactionManager` with a single data source.

Comment: Do you think readOnly as true is a good practice to follow? Or may Bitronix takes more time to execute a query into database.